# How to get values in child class from parent class

Tags: java, polymorphism

I just need help getting a value from the child class, 
this involves polymorphism with this conditions.

First let say I have two class

```
class Parent{
    int i =1;
}

class Child extends Parent{
    int x = 5;
}
```

Then what I want to happened is 
When I do

Parent z = new Child();

I want to get the value of x in the child.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add method `getValueOfX()` to `Parent` and override it in `Child`. You can do different things with it in parent one of the options is to throw an exception, so add to `Parent`:

```
public int getValueOfX() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

And override it in `Child`

```
@Override
public int getValueOfX() {
    return x;
}
```

Another better option is to make the method in `Parent` abstract but then you need to make the whole class abstract:

```
abstract class Parent{
    int i =1;

    abstract public int getValueOfX();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast z to Child

```
Parent z = new Child();
int x = ((Child)z).x;
System.out.println(x);//prints 5
```

Comment: although the first one was a good idea your answer is the one my professor was looking for thanks